# Read integers AND characters from file line by line in C

Tags: c, input, scanf, txt, fgetc

I have a txt file of this form:

```
11
10
BU
1U
0U
0U
...
```

I would like to read each digit/character one by one from the file in C.
The first two rows contain 2 integers, the rest of the rows contain first a letter/integer and then a letter.
I unfortunately do not know how to realize this since you can't know if what you read is an integer or a character.

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Something like `if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) //not a number, read the string`?

Comment: Perhaps `char buf[4]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);`?  Then, process the string.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica thank you. Why is the buffer of size 4 and not 2?

Comment: `fgets()` reads a _line_ and forms a _string_.  How many characters per _line_? First _line_ is likely `'1'`, `'1'`, `'\n'`.  To save that as a _string_ requires how many `char`?  (Note: in C, _strings_ have a _null character_ at the end.)

Comment: Don't be seduced by the patterns into imagining that there will be some "built in" or "easy" way of reading these lines.  The easiest way is going to be the general way.  (1) Read entire lines using `fgets`. (1.5) (optional) Strip the newline that `fgets` left in. (2) (optional) Double-check that the length of the line is 2. (3) Now the first character is `line[0]` and the second character is `line[1]`. (4) Use functions like `isdigit()` and `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>` to determine whether characters are letters or digits.

Comment: (5a) For a line containing two digits, convert it to an `int` by calling `atoi()`. (5b) For a single digit, convert it to an int by saying, for example, `line[0] - '0'`.

Comment: I understand that the first two lines are always integers.  I understand that you're willing to treat them differently.  The "easier" way — except that it's really **not** easier in the long run — would be to use `fscanf` with `%d`.  But `fscanf` mixes very badly with the `fgets` you're going to want to use on the remaining lines, and has numerous other problems.  It really will be easier to read each and every line as a line of plain text, using `fgets`.  Then to convert the first two lines to integers, just use `atoi` on the line you read.  That should be easy enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal exaple on how to address every single character in your file and transforming into integer if one is met. I am sure you could try and adapt this code to your needs.
The code in addition jumps newlines and EOF.

To better understand how this works have a look at the standard [ASCII](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html).

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){
  FILE * handle;
  handle = fopen("data.txt","r");
  char var;

  while(var!=EOF){
    var=fgetc(handle);
    if(var>47&&var<58){
      printf("Value: %d",var);
      printf(" Integer: %d \n",var-48);
    }
    else if(var!=10 && var!=-1){
      printf("Value: %d",var);
      printf(" Char or other: %c\n",var);
  
    }
  }
 
}
```

**Output:**

```
Value: 49 Integer: 1 

Value: 49 Integer: 1

Value: 49 Integer: 1

Value: 48 Integer: 0

Value: 66 Char or other: B

Value: 85 Char or other: U

Value: 49 Integer: 1

Value: 85 Char or other: U

Value: 48 Integer: 0

Value: 85 Char or other: U

Value: 48 Integer: 0

Value: 85 Char or other: U
```

Comment: Thank you! I know that the 2 first lines will surely contain 2 integers, so isn't there a built-in function that suits more for the 2 first lines?

Comment: Instead of saying "To better understand how this works have a look at the standard [ASCII](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html)", and making everyone chase that link and stare at the chart, it's easier all around if you just write `if(var>= '0' && var<='9')` and `printf(" Integer: %d \n", var-'0');`

Comment: I don´t quite understend the question, could you elaborate what you would like to achieve?

Comment: @Erik the first 2 lines in the .txt file are surely 2 digits, the other lines starting from line 3 may contain characters but the 2 first lines only contain integers.

Comment: so isn't there a built-in function that suits more for the 2 first lines? To just take an integer from a file, since I know 100% that it is an integer.

Comment: @SteveSummit the code is clearer like this but somebody that is new to programming would not really get why the numbers have to be written under ' ' , I think that anyone thats able to understand what you are suggesting does not need to stare ad the chart as you say

Comment: @TryerOuter there are many was that you could achive that but since it seems that in your case you need to handle a mixed situation (some times its just integers and sometimes chars are there too) I do´t know it is advisable. If you would know that in total you have more integers than chars you can than reade everthing as a int and then change them to chars so that it would save you some operations.